# CountDownTimer - run one function ontick

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have this **CountDownTimer** and I have an intent in **onTick** and it launches my activity over an over again every second and I want to make it only launch my second activity once how can I do that?

*ps. I want to keep the startActivity() inside the onTick*

Code:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
    //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
    String hms = String.format("Viberation end in: " + "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
     myText.setText(hms);

    Intent toST = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTime.class);

    startActivity(toST);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to start your `Activity` on every tick but you would like to keep calling `startActivity()` inside `onTick()`. How does that make sense?

Comment: I want it to call startActivity() just once it is possible?

Comment: the question you need to ask yourself, is **when** do you want your second activity to start?

Comment: Are you trying to just wait a few milliseconds before launching your activity?  If so, forget the timer stuff and just wrap your code that creates the Intent and the startActivity call in a Runnable and postDelayed on a Handler.

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean variable `launchSecondActivity` and set it to your convenience value, then you said it should be launch only once so ..

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

long millis = millisUntilFinished;
//Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
String hms = String.format("Viberation end in: " + "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
 myText.setText(hms);

Intent toST = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTime.class);
    if(launchSecondActivity){
        launchSecondActivity=false;
        startActivity(toST);
    }

}
```

Comment: It tells me the value set to launchSecondActivity is never used?

Comment: Although technically correct, I don't think this addresses what @Kardio really wants to do.  It just validates a bad way of accomplishing the launching an activity after a delay.